# How to display the selected Item on Bootstrap Dropdown Title in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui

Don't be mean because I'm new to Angular. So I have a bootstrap Dropdown component in my project and I would like to change the text of the button depending on the clicked link.

On the internet, I've only come across JQuery [implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/cmcculloh/xnpf1rr9/).

So does anyone know how to do this in Angularjs? Thanks in advance.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/GpQpYG) sandbox

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller='DropdownCtrl'>

    <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
      <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
        Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
        <li role="menuitem">
          <a href="#">Action</a>
          <a href="#">Another action</a>
          <a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('DropdownCtrl', function ($scope) {

});
```

Comment: Yep use a data from the controller on the button text, one sec..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Considering you have the basic data binding knowledge on Angularjs. Try this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjagZR. If you don't understand something from here feel free to ask.

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
<div ng-controller='DropdownCtrl'>

<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
  <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
    {{button}} <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
    <li role="menuitem">
      <a href="#" ng-click="change(action)" ng-repeat="action in actions">{{action}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('DropdownCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.button = "Button dropdown";
  $scope.actions = [
    "Action", "Another Action", "Something else here"
  ];

  $scope.change = function(name){
    $scope.button = name;
  }
});
```

Comment: Lol beat me to it. This is what I was just typing out.

Comment: Wow, you nailed this.

Answer (score 2):

you use Custom Directive because directive is make once use any where:

this is directive name  : **dropdown-text-set**

required this directive only ID name : **angular_menu_item**

```
restrict : "A",
link : function(scope, ele, attr)
{
  var dropdown_item = angular.element(document.getElementById("angular_menu_item")).children();
  for(var i = 0; i<dropdown_item.length; i++)       {
    dropdown_item.eq(i).bind("click", function($event){

      ele.html($event.target.innerHTML+'<span class="caret">');
    });
  }
}
```

see this example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoYjqy

Comment: Instead of attaching a click handler to each item, you can use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) `ele.on('click', '.dropdown-menu > li > a', function(event) {...});`