# Checkbox in dropdown menu is not checked from previously selected value in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, ng-class

I am new to AngularJS. I am trying to get the checkbox to appear as checked from previously selected value. I thought ng-class would do the trick but it's not. Did I do anything wrong in the code below?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu menu-content" uib-dropdown-menu>
      <li ng-repeat="value in values" >
      <label><input type="checkbox" ng-class="{'checked' : value.selected, 'active' : value.selected}" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleValue(value)">{{value.valueName}}</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<body>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []);
    app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
      // dummy data
      $scope.value = 1; // some value
    });

  </script>

  <div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="value === 1">
  </div>


</body>
```

Use inbuilt ng-checked directive of angular.

Comment: I tried both ng-checked="value.selected" and ng-model="value.selected" and they both worked but I don't know what the differences are. One thing I notice is that ng-model doesn't work on dynamically displaying multi-selected values on bootstrap drop-down menu. Something similar to this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjagZR but with multi-selected values. (Reference from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278097/how-to-display-the-selected-item-on-bootstrap-dropdown-title-in-angular)

Comment: ng-checked is angular provided directive that marks checkbox as checked if its value is truthy. Use it instead of ng-model to avoid any unexpected bug since it is made for that purpose.